# material-ui: unable to style Icon Menu

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm not able to styling `Icon Menu` even if I used `listStyle` or `menuStyle`   I just need to change the position like this

[image]

it was like this

[image]

Update:

example:

```
   import React from 'react';
import IconMenu from 'material-ui/IconMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import MoreVertIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/more-vert';


const IconMenuExampleSimple = () => (
  <div>
    <IconMenu
      iconButtonElement={<IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>}
      anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
      targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
      listStyle={{top: 80}} //this not work
      menuStyle={{top: 80}} //this not work
    >
      <MenuItem primaryText="Refresh" />
      <MenuItem primaryText="Send feedback" />
      <MenuItem primaryText="Settings" />
      <MenuItem primaryText="Help" />
      <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" />
    </IconMenu>

  </div>
);

export default IconMenuExampleSimple;
```

Comment: Please add a code example

Comment: @Berendschot Yes sorry for that, I forgot it. Can you please check it now

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but you can use `anchorOrigin={{vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'left}}`; nevertheless... yeah that old version of material-ui is a pain in the knee to style, menuStyle just add styles to a deep nested div, not the menu itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Customizing menu position**

By default, the menu will display below (y-axis), after (x-axis), without overlapping its trigger. The position can be changed using the xPosition (before | after) and yPosition (above | below) attributes. The menu can be forced to overlap the trigger using the overlapTrigger attribute.

**Here is code.**.

```
<mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu" yPosition="above">
  <button mat-menu-item>Settings</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Help</button>
</mat-menu>
```